# Slack event appends to list within the decorator function but it doesn't append to list outside the decorator function

Tags: python, slack-api

```
message_text = []


@slack_event_adapter.on("message")
def message(payload):
    event = payload.get("event", {})
    channel_id = event.get("channel")
    user_id = event.get("user")

    # each user has an ID, loop through every user's id, find their name in user_in_channel return their name.
    if user_id:
        if user_id in users_in_channel:
            username = users_in_channel[user_id]


    text = event.get("text")
    time_stamp = event.get("ts")
    time_stamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(float(time_stamp))).strftime(
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    )

    time_stamp_string_to_datetime = datetime.strptime(time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    b = datetime.now()




    message_text.append(text)
    print(message_text) # here it returns the message string within a list.  

print(message_text) # here it returns an empty list.
```

**The first print within the function appends to the list and prints the message.
The second print returns an empty list.**

I want to understand what exactly is the cause for this. I have other functions that manipulate the message and reply to the user in the same channel which ends up sending many messages instead of one message. calling it outside the function will avoid the loop which is why I am trying to call the list outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The "second print" in this code as is, is actually executed as soon as the program starts, and before it can receive any events.

Python programs are resolved line by line - but upon finding a function (or class) definition, Python "learns"that function and whatever code is inside will just be executed when the function is called.

Here, your listing is not complete - or maybe there are other files that import this - the fact is that in order to be abel to receive external messsages in your decorated function, at some point your program pass the control to a "loop" which will listen for slack events, and then call the registered functions when they arrive.

Your second print is in the module body, before passing the control of the program to the loop that will actually deal with the network events: the list *is* empty at this point.

To act upon receiving messages you should either call the function that will perform your action from inside the decorated function, so that it will take place when an event arrives, or arrange some other way for your acting function to be called after you pass the control to the API loop - either by using multi-threading and polling the data structure (your list) each few units of time, or, which would be better, registering your action-function to be called by the main loop at definite time intervals. (*if* the slack api loop offer this option at all).